# Application can't create a writable folder with Vagrant

Tags: permissions, vagrant, file-permissions

I configured my own basic Vagrant Box from Vagrant's Official Precise64 box. I have a synced folder located here "/var/www" and the public folder located at "/var/www/public".

For "/var/www", my permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant
```

For "/var/www/public", my permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant vagrant
```

To illustrate my issue, with WordPress applications, I have manually set the permissions of uploads to 777. WordPress is able to create a folder inside of uploads for the month, such as "/var/www/public/wp-content/uploads/10/"; however, it can't upload or write to the folder it just made unless I again manually change the permissions of the newly created "10" folder to be writable.

This happens with all applications such as Laravel's "storage" folder and basically anytime a program tries to create a directory. Trying to force the permissions to set on Vagrant Up during provisioning is also not working:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/path/to/writable/folder", "/path/to/writable/folder", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

So, what permissions do I need to set on virtual server to enable this to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've used both WordPress and Laravel in Vagrant and set write permissions in the Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=774','fmode=775']`

And also add the default Apache user to the `vagrant` group (I use shell provisioning):

`usermod -a -G vagrant www-data`

Comment: This works. For my case, "config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]" is also working. Thanks

Comment: wouldn't this make all folders in vagrant writable? what if one wants to make specific folders writable. I am thinking of having only the /cache folder writable and the rest as they are.

Comment: For Homestead users that want to make use of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056933/3017716

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon the answer of [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4143923/jesse-overright), when using homestead (and thus Homestead.yaml) you can pass these options through like this

```
folders:
- map: ./
  to: /home/vagrant/code
  options:
    mount_options: ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
```

Based on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#configuring-homestead and https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#modifying-the-owner-group

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following line to your Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :group => "www-data", :mount_options => ['dmode=775','fmode=664']
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?